# How do you earn extra continues in Super Mario Land?

Tags: super-mario-land

Sometimes after getting a game over in Super Mario Land, I’ll have one or two continues I can use to keep playing. I think I earned the continues during gameplay, but I’m not sure how I got them.

How do you earn extra continues in Super Mario Land?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to page 12 of the English instruction booklet and multiple guides on Gamefaqs (such as [here](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/gameboy/585933-super-mario-land/faqs/50622) and [here](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/gameboy/585933-super-mario-land/faqs/8612)), a continue is given for every 100,000 points you gain.

Like a lot of old Game Boy games, these things aren't immediately obvious unless you have seen the manual (which are probably rarer than the games these days!).